# A question about conditional probability

Tags: probability

I'm new to the field so this is a pretty simple question, but let's say I know that $P(A|B) = 0.6$ and and that $P(B) = 0.3$.

Is there a way to tell $P(A)$ given this information?

Comment: first equation in wikipedia... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}.$$

If $A$ and $B$ are **independent** events, then
$$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B),$$
so that
$$P(A|B) = P(A).$$

Otherwise, it would not be possible to compute $P(A)$ from $P(A|B)$ and $P(B)$, without additional information.